# Upload project from Android Studio to a different Github account

Tags: android-studio, github, github-for-windows

I was working on an Android Studio Project and I had uploaded it to my Github account by using Android Studio's Version Control option, following simple steps:

VCS >> Import into Version Control >> Share Project on Github

Now, I have created another project in Android Studio and I want to upload it to a different Github Account that I own. But every time I follow the above mentioned steps to upload it, the project is uploaded on the same Github account on which I uploaded my previous project.

Is there a way I can upload it to a different Github account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File/Settings/Version Control/Github

then change your github login id and password. Then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now when I follow these steps: VCS>>Import into Version Control>>Share Project on Github,, it says: can't add remote fatal remote origin already exists. Any idea why?